# how do I get multiple a tag href links (in form of an array) from inside an iframe (puppeteer)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, iframe, puppeteer

Pretty new to coding, which is why this question might be easily answered, but after scanning the internet for 2 days now and still not having a real solution, i thought I'd just ask here.

So, as the title explains, I have an iframe inside a website I want to scrape with an id attribute (we'll just call it *iframeid*) and somewhere inside this iframe I have a div container with a class attribute (we'll call it *divclass*) that contains - besides other elements - multiple `<a>` tags. My goal is to get an array in which all the links from those `<a>` tags are listed, put to date I only achieved the following through researching and a bit of luck:

```
const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('iframe#iframeid');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.waitForSelector('div[class=divclass] a');
var x = 2; //a var to determine which a tag I want
const oneA= await frame.$('div[class=entryLayer] a:nth-child(' + x + ')');
const link = await (await oneA.getProperty('href'))._remoteObject.value;
console.log(link);
```

What it does is it takes a variable and pulls the link of its according `<a>` tag, but I can't figure out how to put it in a loop and besides that, the amount of `<a>` tags varies, which makes the loop for me to code even harder.

Wouldn't it even be possible to leave out the loop completely?  I found similar stackoverflow questions, but one for example only had one `<a>` tag which seems to change the code completely.

At the end I just want a working piece of code that I as a newbie can understand but is fairly compact at the same time.
Thanks for helping in advance!

**EDIT**

My solution with the help of a comment:

```
const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('iframe#iframeid');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
const thisDiv = await frame.waitForSelector('div[class=divclass]');
const xpath_expression = '//a[@href]';
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expression);
const links = await thisDiv.$x(xpath_expression);
const link_urls = await thisDiv.evaluate((...links) => {
    return links.map(e => e.href);
}, ...links);
console.log(link_urls);
```

It does pull out some strange other links though, but I'm just going to filter them out normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know in every iframe can be treated as different page. Here is the reference I used for the same type of task https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940865/17755263

Comment: I wasn't able to get the idea with  `/a/@href`  working quickly, could you provide a more specific piece of code? Besides that, could there be any differences between php (your post) and javascript (my question)?

Comment: I can do this but you should try yourself.

Hint : Javascript is client side. So all code will be treated equally both within iframe and outside iframe

Comment: ok, I'll try it later in more detail, thanks!

Comment: I got it to work somehow, thanks for your hint! Going to add my solution to my question